# How to limit multipart file upload size at jboss level?

Tags: file-upload, jboss7.x, resteasy

My application is running on jboss AS7+RestEasy, currently I am handling file size limit in my APi as

```
@POST
@GZIP
@RequestFilter
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Path("/demo/test")
public String uploadTest(
        @MultipartForm UPFile uploadFileFile,
        ) {
if (uploadFileFile.getFileSize() > 10*10*1024) {
//error.. 
}
}
```

Where I get fileSize as @FormParm, this works for me.

Issue is that uploadTest() this api gets called after file is uploaded to jboss container, and then it check for file size this takes unnecessarily server resources (Say client uploads 1GB data this data will be uploaded to server) I am looking for something that rejects files once they exceed size of 10MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to your web.xml can help you.

```
 <multipart-config>  
          <max-file-size>5120000</max-file-size>  
          <max-request-size>5120000</max-request-size>  
        </multipart-config>
```

Comment: thanks vineet for quick response but <multipart-config> or @MultipartConfig annotation works only in servlets we are using rest apis (restEasy), I have tried adding above to <servlet>
  <servlet-name>RestEasy</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>   but din't helped.

Comment: John, you can use [link]http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Interceptors.html#PreProcessInterceptors and put the logic inside the interceptor.

Comment: With JAX-RS 2.0, you could use a ContainerRequestFilter bound to your upload method using a @NameBinding annotation. In this filter, you would look at the content-length request header and discard the request if the content length exceeds the maximum value you plan to accept (requestContext.abortWith(...))

Comment: Note that the `Content-Length` header is written by the client so this will work if your client does not lie.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `max-post-size` attribute in the relevant connector in web subsystem.

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="10485760"/>
```